# Why are my ASP.NET security stamps not being revalidated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, cookies

I have an ASP.NET site using cookie based authentication. I am trying to stop concurrent logins and shared logins for our users who are sharing their credentials. I had the validation interval set up at 30 minutes, but even when I set it to 1 minute or a zero timespan, nothing happens.

When debugging locally, I can sign in on chrome, then sign in on another window, but the first login does not get forced out, even after waiting for the validation interval to pass or refreshing the page.

What am I not understanding?

Thanks!

Login page logic:

```
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

if (user == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return Page();
}

// Update the security stamp for the user
// This makes sure all other computers/browsers are logged out
// when the cookie/credentials are checked next
await _signInManager.UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);

// Attempt to sign in the user
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    return RedirectToReturnUrl(returnUrl);
}
else if (result.IsLockedOut)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your account is locked out.");
    return Page();
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return Page();
}
```

Startup code:

```
// Set the security stamp options
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;// TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.OnRefreshingPrincipal = context =>
    {
        // Custom claims logic excluded
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    };
});

// Add the authentication state provider
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<MyCustomIdentityUser>>();
```

`RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider.cs`:

```
public class RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<TUser> : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider where TUser : class
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private readonly IdentityOptions _options;

    public RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(loggerFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        _options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.Zero;// TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
        AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
        var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        try
        {
            var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<TUser>>();
            return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (scope is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
            {
                await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<TUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(_options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
            var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            return principalStamp == userStamp;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried reducing the validation intervals and updating the security stamps.  If I manually update the security stamps in the database, it also doesn't force a logout of the user.